# Oracle denies login for newly created users

Tags: oracle, authentication, ora-01017

I came across this issue setting up new users for a **German** Oracle 18c Enterprise database.
All of a sudden the logon is denied for any newly created user. See below:

`connect updatest/1234567@orcl18c;`

```
Fehler beim Start in Zeile: 3 in Befehl -
  connect ...
Fehlerbericht -
Verbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden
  USER          = updatest
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = QM-DB.GERADLINIG.com)(PORT = 1521))    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***.com)(PORT = 15218))    (CONNECT_DATA =      (SERVER = DEDICATED)      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl18c.***)    )  )
  Fehlermeldung = ORA-01017: Benutzername/Kennwort ungültig; Anmeldung abgelehnt
Commit
```

`select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee='updatest';`

[image]

Whereas I can login with a similar user that was created some weeks earlier. See here:

`connect qm_ta_12.1/1234567@orcl18c;`

```
Angemeldet.
Mit CONNECT-Skriptbefehl erstellte Verbindung beendet
```

**They have the same system privileges!** I ran out of ideas what could be the problem as the password is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username was converted to uppercase by Oracle internally without any signs of it. I guess I will stick to using only uppercase letters for usernames in Oracle to avoid running in this dilemma again.

Answer (score 2):

At the first sight, looks pretty obvious:

> Fehlermeldung = ORA-01017

ORA-01017 means **invalid username/password**.

Comment: I have created the user at least 5 times now and there is no way that I mistyped the password that many times.

Comment: then your only other possibility is that you're in the wrong database

Comment: also, you know that passwords are case-sensitive? from inside a sqlplus session, try creating the user AND then issuing a CONNECT command to the new user from that admin session

Comment: I'll do that, but how can case-sensitivity be an issue when my password consists of digits only?

Comment: Creating the user from within an sqlplus session worked and I can now use that user to log in. The username was converted to uppercase by oracle, but doesn't really seem to matter. I don't see any difference compared to before, but it does work now. Thank you for the suggestion.